# What is the best way to increase view counter column of a row in each select?

Tags: sql, database, performance

Often with portals like news sites, I wonder whether it is good practice or not to update view counter field of a table while selecting the row. Lets say I have a News table with id, title, details, publishDate and viewCounter. Is it good to perform following query on each request of news detail page? How would this mixing of select and update together for each request hurt performance?

```
select * from News where id=120;
update News
set viewCounter=viewCounter+1
where id=120;
```

Could there be any difference in performance if I put view tracker data in another table, say table ViewsCount with columns id, newsID,viewCount? In this case, I would execute following code:

```
select * from News where id=120;
update ViewsCount
set viewCount=viewCount+1
where newsID=120;
```

I would see one more option where I would track browser request data for each request, and later aggregate the rows for each news id. With this design, I would run two queries for each request: select and insert, like following:

```
select * from News where id=120;
insert into NewsView(newsID,browser,ipAddress,operatingSystem,col1,col2)
values(120,'Netscape','202.xx.xx.xx','Windows',col1Value,col2Value)
```

But with this I have seen that in short span of time I would get lots of rows and database size also increases significantly with heavy traffic portals. This would definitely slow down aggregate queries.

What are the alternatives I could use? Or is it ok to go with page view trackers like Google Analytics? I would welcome suggestions based on best practices you have been following in the similar context.

Answer (score 2):

Updating a row for every view will take an exclusive lock on that row effectively serializing read access to that resource, as each queuing read transaction will need to wait for the previous one to commit which in turn requires confirmation that the transaction log has been persisted to disc.

This will quickly become a bottle neck for even moderately popular articles.

I would consider tracking page view deltas in memory in the application and just writing them to the database at periodic intervals. If the application crashes you will lose the views for that period but this may well be acceptable.

Alternatively your web server may well have log files that are appended to on each view and can be periodically parsed to extract information about new page views.